# Why Typescript Interface Not Render In Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have been working with TypeScript for a week now. I am stuck on [interfaces](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_interfaces.htm); here I am unable to figure out how TypeScript converts an interface into JavaScript, as it does not appear in the JavaScript code after compiling.

**TypeScript**

```js
interface IPerson { 
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  sayHi: () => string; 
}

var customer: IPerson = { 
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Hanks", 
  sayHi: (): string => { return "Hi there" } 
} 

console.log("Customer Object ") 
console.log(customer.firstName) 
console.log(customer.lastName) 
console.log(customer.sayHi())
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var customer = {
firstName: "Tom",
lastName: "Hanks",
sayHi: function () { return "Hi there"; }
};
console.log("Customer Object ");
console.log(customer.firstName);
console.log(customer.lastName);
console.log(customer.sayHi());
```

Comment: It *doesn't* convert the interface to JS. TS only exists at compile time, at run time it's all just JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concepts such as interfaces don't exist in plain JavaScript. Interfaces only exist in TypeScript where they are used to guarantee that usages and definitions adhere to the contract.

```
interface Post {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}
```

The above definition is used by the compiler to guarantee that the contract is respected:

```
const goingToNewYork: Post = {
  id: '123-455-222-111',
}
```

[image]

Once the job of  type checking is done, typescript simply compiles ts to plain javascript (which omits declarations).

- Declarations can be outputted to separate files, normally known as `d.ts`:
  https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html

Answer (score 0):

Like my file name is= interface1.ts, so
At first you have to written in terminal your file name like =>(1) tsc interface1.ts
Then Enter, After that,
=>(2) node interface1.js

Then it will convert typescript to JavaScript and  you will get output
***but at first you have to install typescript in vs code, commend is=>npm install -g typescript

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is about why interfaces are not transpiled to JS, you seem to answer how to run `tsc`